# Is it correct that skb->data_len , skb->len , skb->mac_len value is 0?

Tags: c, netfilter

When I use netfilter API,

```
iph = ip_hdr(skb);
saddr = iph->saddr;        //unsigned long
daddr = iph->daddr;        //unsigned long
```

but `saddr` and `daddr` are incorrect values.

So I tested

```
printk("len = %u , data_len = %u , mac_len = %u , hdr_len = %u\n",skb->len , skb->data_len , skb->mac_len , skb->hdr_len);
printk("truesize = %u , data = %x\n",skb->truesize , &skb->data);
```

The result is:

[image]

is this correct?

Comment: The value extracted from `skb` seem to be not well assigned. Please add text in your question instead of image and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2):

Try extract this way:

```
struct iphdr *ip_hdr = (struct iphdr *)skb_network_header(skb);
```

and access this way:

```
printk("source address = %u  destination address = %u\n", ip_hdr->saddr, ip_hdr->daddr);
```